# Actions to create secret on K8S

Tags: azure, github, kubernetes, github-actions

I'm trying to create a secret in k8s using `github actions` like following (I've pre step which install lightweight k8s - k3s)

```
  - name: example tests
    shell: bash
    env:
      SUPER_SECRET: ${{ secrets.KUBECONFIG }}
   run: |
       kubectl create secret generic mysec --from-literal="$SUPER_SECRET" -n default
```

But I got error, any idea how to do it using github actions?

I use the `settings->secrets` and create a `KUBECONFIG` value and put the file content

in my local env I created a secret successfully  with a `kubeconfig` file like:

```
 kubectl create secret generic mysec --from-file=./kubeconfig -n default
```

But in the CI I want to use it from the secret env in github ...

The error is: `Error: Error: The process '/usr/local/bin/kubectl' failed with exit code 1`

Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open '/home/runner/work/_temp/*** *** *** *** *** ***

What am I missing here?

I tried also with

`kubectl create secret generic mysec --from-literal kubeconfig=$SUPER_SECRET -n default`

If there is other way to make it work please let me know.

Comment: Are you operating on GitHub or Azure DevOps? I am a little confused because you have typed both tags.

Comment: @JaneMa-MSFT - remove it, thanks. do you have any idea or a way to overcome this?